# Text animations stop when the image come back to first image

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm building a website, the front page have an image slider with a text on it.

At first it starts nicely, but when the image comes back to the start, the text animation is stopped. Can someone help me to make the text animation keep showing?

This is what I've done:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("captiontxt");
  var tmp = container.innerHTML;
  container.innerHTML = tmp;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active2", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active2";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 6000);
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
.fade2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 4.5s;
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes dropHeader {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
.captiontxt {
  color: #fff!important;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #0062f6!important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation-name: dropHeader;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-name: dropHeader;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides fade2">
  <img src="image put in here" style="width: 100%; height:640px;"> 
  <div class="captiontxt">Write the text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet. Please fix it by adding missing code such as the "dots"

Comment: `animation-iteration-count: 1;` is probably your culprit here. Because its defined on the standard class, this is not reset when you animate things, so it will be forever stop executing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` & `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;` to achieve a reiterating animation as per your requirement.

Refer code:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("captiontxt");
  var tmp = container.innerHTML;
  container.innerHTML = tmp;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 6000);
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
.fade2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 4.5s;
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes dropHeader {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
.captiontxt {
  color: #fff!important;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #0062f6!important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation-name: dropHeader;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-name: dropHeader;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides fade2">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/89/2f/7d/892f7d36162123ab12344958a2cf5f2c.jpg" style="width: 100%; height:640px;">
  <div class="captiontxt">Write the text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i use infinite the text section will keep moving continuosly in every image and after one rotation (come back to the start image) it stopped. is it because of the cache or not?

Comment: No, its not because of the cache. That is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I slowed it down a bit (from .6 s to 1.2 s) but the snippet should help. The infinite animation count basically loops the animation, regardless of the number of images. However, should you want to change the text per image, this may not be the correct course of action. Comment on the answer if you are thinking of doing this.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;

showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("captiontxt");
  var tmp = container.innerHTML;
  container.innerHTML = tmp;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active2", "");
  }
  slideIndex++;

  if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }  
   
  slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides,5000);
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
.fade2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 4.5s;
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes dropHeader {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
.captiontxt {
  color: #fff!important;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #0062f6!important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation-name: dropHeader;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: dropHeader;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides fade2">
  <img src="image put in here" style="width: 100%; height:640px;">
  <p class="captiontxt dots">Write the text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: each image has its own text.

Answer (score 0):

The Complete Code, The text describe of each image (didn't change as long as each the image is the same)

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();

    function showSlides() {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
        //var container = document.getElementsByClassName("captiontxt");
        //var tmp = container.innerHTML;
        //container.innerHTML = tmp;
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active2", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active2";
        setTimeout(showSlides, 6000); // Change image every 5 seconds
    }

<!-- language: lang-css -->

* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slideshow-container {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        height: 600px;
    }
.active2 {
        background-color: #717171;
    }
.dots {
        height: 13px;
        width: 13px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: background-color 4.0s ease;
}
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
.fade2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 4.5s;
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes dropHeader {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
.captiontxt {
  color: #fff!important;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #0062f6!important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation-name: dropHeader;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-name: dropHeader;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <%--repeat this section as much as the number of image--%>
        <div class="mySlides fade2">
            <img src="images.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 640px;">
            <div class="captiontxt"><a href="#" style="color: #ffffff">Text 1<br />Text 2</a></div>
        </div>
        <%--end section--%>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align: center; visibility: hidden;">
        <%--repeat this section as much as the number of image--%>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <%--end section--%>
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```